# Can't send selected option to database [cannot be null error]

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to send the data from option, and I'm getting this error *"Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'marka' cannot be null' in "*

Can anyone help or explain as why in this case the $marka doesn't actually get data from the selected option.

```
$marka = $_POST['marka'];

$stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO users(
            vEmri,marka, vPic) 
      VALUES(:uemri,:umarka,:upic)');
            $stmt->bindParam(':uemri',$vEmri);
            $stmt->bindParam(':umarka',$marka);
            $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$vPic);

            if($stmt->execute())
            {
                $successMSG = "User added ...";
                header("refresh:5;index.php"); // redirects image view page after 5 seconds.
            }
```

T

```
<?php
 try {
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbo);
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
      exit;
 }

 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM marka WHERE `status` = 1 ORDER BY marka_name ASC';
 $q = $conn->query($sql);
 $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<tr>
    <td><label class="control-label">Marka:</label></td>
    <td><select name="marka" id="marka">
         <option name="marka" id="marka">Zgjedh marken</option>
             <?php while ($row = $q->fetch()){ ?>
                 <option  value="<?php echo $row['marka_id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['marka_name']; ?></option>
             <?php } ?>
         </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

> Error:
>   Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'marka' cannot be null' in add.php:88

Comment: where is `vEmri` and `vPic` defined?

Comment: and you do not need a `name` and an `id` on `<option name="marka" id="marka">`, just leave the `<select name="marka" id="marka">` so that it gets the proper value

Comment: They are defined, I just didn't post here.. So just use the name for option?

Comment: time to read about HTML select option https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: Leaving just select didn't work either

Comment: Send an object instead of a string in `data`. Like this `data: {marka_id: markaID}`

Comment: You are sending `marka_id` -> `data:'marka_id='+markaID,`, but expecting `marka` -> `$marka = $_POST['marka'];`. Unless I am missing something `marka_id` != `marka`

Comment: @diddledot sending data to ajaxData.php is fine, the problem is the upper code which sends it to database.

Comment: @sean ofc marka_id != marka, by $marka=$_POST['marka']; I'm trying to get directly the value of selected option and send it to database.

Comment: Have you tried a `print_r($_POST)`/`var_dump($_POST)` to see what is there, and why `$_POST['marka']` is null?

Comment: @sean I can't/don't know how since this error redirects to a blank page and shows just the error.

Comment: In your code here you have `$marka = $_POST['marka'];`. But in the full code dump (http://paste.ofcode.org/38vhM97jS57c7mnBgG76JT6) you have `$marka = $_POST['markaID'];`. Have you tried changing the `$_POST['markaID']` to`$_POST['marka']`?

Comment: @sean That was just because I was testing it with markaID, it doesn't work with 'marka' either.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look, you have wrote in your code.

```
<option name="marka" id="marka">Zgjedh marken</option>
```

But this is wrong , Please correct this line and try. (You should remove name and id from here, and need to add value with this option)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Tried it not working. a link of the full code: http://paste.ofcode.org/38vhM97jS57c7mnBgG76JT6 

Error:
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'marka' cannot be null' in add.php:88

Comment: name of dropdown is 'marka' (<select class="form-control" id="marka" name="marka">) but when you fetching the value, you are using 'markaID' instead of 'marka' ($marka = $_POST['markaID']).

Comment: That was just because I was testing it in other form $_POST['marka'] doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the problem actually was so I started rewriting the same code again.

I write the same code and now it works, and I still can't figure out why it wasn't actually working.

Posting the whole code since I don't know what was the problem and I can't define here.

*edited:
I think this might be a server side error or something else, it looks like a limit to send multiple variables to database, now it gets $zbritja as NULL.*